# Distinctcount - suppliers for departments over a period of time - slow performance

Tags: mdx, olap, iccube

In a model that contains the following dimensions:
- Time - granularity month - 5 years - 20 quarters - 60 months
- Suppliers- 6000 suppliers at lowest level
- departments - 500 departments on lowest level

I need to have the distinct count of the suppliers for each department.

I use the function:

```
with member [measures].[#suppliers] as
distinctcount(([Supplier].[Supplier].[supplier].members
   ,[Measures].[amount]))
)
select [Measures].[#suppliers] on 0
, order([Department].[Department].[department].members, [#suppliers], BDESC) on 1
from [cube]
where [Time].[Time].[2017 10]:[Time].[Time].[2018 01]
```

The time component may vary, as the dashboard user is free to choose a reporting period.

But the MDX is very slow. It takes about 38ms to calculate the measure for each row. I want to use this measure to rank the departments and to calculate a cumulative % and assign scores to these values. As you can imagine performance will not improve.

I have tried to use functions and cache the result, but results - for me - got worse (according to the log 2x as bad).

What can I do to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go fast adding a measure that calculates de Distinct Count on the Supplier ID of the table associated to[Measures].[Amount] will help. In the Schema definition.

The other ones are not scalable as Supplier is growing.

Nonetheless, why did you use DistinctCount instead of Count(NonEmpty())) ?

[DistinctCount](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/DistinctCount.php) is mainly for calculating the number of members/tuples that are different in a set. It only makes sense if it's possible to have two same members in a set. As our initial members have no duplicated, it's useless.

[Count](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Count.php)([NonEmpty](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/NonEmpty.php)()) filters the set whith the nonempty and counts the number of items in the set. This can be easily calculated in parallel

Comment: In my real case, supplier is not a leaf, but the level just before the leaf level. With your hints I did a small experiment:

1. distinctcount - amount - supplier linked to facts at max(ordinal) -1
2. count distinct non empty - same
3. distinctcount - dummy value - supplier linked to leaf in new fact
4. count distinct non empty - same

results:
1. 1542 ms
2. 1474 ms
3. 0651 ms
4. 0730 ms

Comment: Conclusion: the count level does not matter so much, but there is a huge difference between distinctcount and count (distinct(nonempth())) as you hinted.

Why is that? I just picked the distinctcount as it matched my requirement - when I read the documentation. So I had no specific reason.

Comment: ----
Just tested with the ranking algoritm, but the query is now coming back, but takes a total of 242.8 seconds(!).

Comment: the distinct is useless if your set  is build with all members of a level or hierarchy. We didn't document DistinctCount( {member}, [Mesure] ),did we ?

Comment: No you did not. I see I made a mistake while tranlating my MDX to this example. It should have been distinctcount(([Supplier].[Supplier].[supplier].members
   ,[Measures].[amount])), with double brackets. I will edit it in the original MDX.

Comment: why do you need a distinct on a set that is unique ?

Comment: Let's zoom-out ...
I need the unique suppliers (that have data) for each department, for a given time period.

Both the MDX statements: --- distinctcount(( <suppliers level>.members, [amount] )) --- and --- count(distinct((nonempty(<suppliers level>.members,[amount]),[amount]))) --- give me the right answers. I do not see where it is wrong, so I have difficulty answering your question. --- If I count the number of tuples in a given period for a supplier & department combination I have more than 1 combination, namely lots of suppliers selling to a department on different dates.

Comment: <suppliers level>.members is an unique list, how does applying distinct is going to change something ? -> unique({1,2,3,4,5})  is {1,2,3,4,5}. For unique to make sense you need twice the same, how could this be possible ?

Comment: ok, now I see what you mean: I can shorten it to count(nonempty(<suppliers level>.members,[amount])!